# Populate result of another query into combo box

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have an Excel file for colleagues to extract reports from SQL server.

We created separate user and password for their department.

I have the module which shows the result of SQL query in an Excel file.

Here is working code:

```vb
Sub Button3_Click()

    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

    Dim qt As QueryTable

    sqlstring1 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ReportDataAdded ORDER BY ProductID, CountryCodeID"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=getConnectionStr2, Destination:=Range("A3"), Sql:=sqlstring1)

        .Refresh

    End With

End Sub

Private Function getConnectionStr2()
getConnectionStr2 = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
                   "DATABASE=em_CountryConsumer;" & _
                   "SERVER=192.192.192.192;" & _
                   "UID=UserName;" & _
                   "PWD=passwordd;"
End Function
```

I need to populate the result of another query into combo box. For that I need to get result of query into variable with dataset datatype.

How can I change my VBA code to do that?

Comment: it's a bit unclear what do you expect. But, my suggestion is to use ADODO (ADO) instead of (terrible) QueryTables. You will find tones of examples everywhere in internet for how ADO works.

Comment: I agree with Kaz, you should use ADO. Then you should place the result of the query into a separate sheet (this can be hidden). Once the data  is in the sheet you can create combo boxes (or edit existing) so the values reference the column of data in the query result sheet.

Comment: @ryanG I think I know how to do it, it should not be a problem. Just one question how to refresh combobox cell range? Cause one day there will be 20 values. Second day there will be 15 values, so I will have 5 blank spaces in combobox, third day it will be 25 values and I will have 5 missing values. Is it possible to automatize this?

Comment: @Almazini I'm assuming that the values are updating every time that macro is run to re-query the database and pull new values. Make sure the result sheet is cleaned everytime, and at the end of that method just set the combo box values to a new range depicted by, "range(cells(start_row, col_num), cells(start_row+(total_query_result_rows-1), col_num)". Then make sure to set combobox index to 0 [or 1] to reset the default value that was in the combobox previously.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I have handled a similar problem in the past:

First here is a function to Query the database based with a given connection_string and query.

```vb
Function GetQuery(SQL As String, connect_string As String, Optional HasFields As Long = 0) As Variant
    '''
    ' Returns: A Variant() Array with results from query.
    '
    ' HasFields is an optional field to include the field names in the array
    '   Any integer in this field will include fields, leave it blank for just data
    '''
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim data_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim dbArr() As Variant

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Setting Up DB connection
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
conReTry:
    On Error GoTo ConnectErr:
    With Conn
        .ConnectionString = connect_string
        .Open
    End With

ConnectErr:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "There was an issue connecting to the Central DB."
        Resume subexit
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

     ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Starting the connection to DB
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error GoTo QueryErr:
    RS.Open SQL, Conn, adOpenStatic
QueryErr:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "There was a problem with the Query. Could not get results from the statement:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        dbArr = Array(" Failed Q ", " Failed Q ")
        Resume subexit
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    '''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Parse Data and fill array: DBarr
    '''''''''''''''''''''
    R = 0
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim tmp_rowNum As LongPtr, tmp_colNum As LongPtr
        Dim rowNum As Integer, colNum As Integer
        tmp_rowNum = RS.RecordCount
        tmp_colNum = RS.Fields.Count
        rowNum = CLng(tmp_rowNum)
        colNum = CLng(tmp_colNum)
    #Else
        Dim rowNum As Long, colNum As Long
        rowNum = RS.RecordCount
        colNum = RS.Fields.Count
    #End If


    If HasFields = 0 Then
        ReDim dbArr(1 To rowNum + 1, 1 To colNum)
    Else
        ReDim dbArr(1 To rowNum + 2, 1 To colNum)
    End If
    Do While Not RS.EOF
        R = R + 1
        For C = 1 To RS.Fields.Count
            If R = 1 And HasFields = 1 Then
                dbArr(R, C) = RS.Fields(C - 1).Name
            ElseIf Not R = 1 Then
                dbArr(R, C) = RS.Fields(C - 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        If Not R = 1 Then RS.MoveNext
    Loop

subexit:
    GetQuery = dbArr
    Set Conn = Nothing
    Set RS = Nothing
End Function
```

Next use the result of the Query (A [multi-dimensional] Array) to set the range in a worksheet:

```vb
Sub SetInitData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim sql_string As String, connect_String as String
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(config.DATA_SHEET_NAME)

    sql_string = config.GET_INITIAL_PACKTYPE_QUERY
    connect_string = config.MAIN_CONNECTION_STRING

    Debug.Print sql_string

    Dim packtypedata As Variant

    packtypedata = GetQuery(sql_string)

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(UBound(packtypedata), UBound(packtypedata, 2))).Value = packtypedata

    '' Keep Total Rows for next routine explained below
    Dim total_rows as Integer
    total_rows = UBound(packtypedata)
    SetComboBoxValues(total_rows)
    ''' Turn on events and screen updating again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Finally you want to set the ComboBox:

```vb
Sub SetComboBoxValues(total_rows As Integer)
    Dim ws as Worksheet, data_ws as Worksheet
    Dim data_arr as Variant
    Dim pack_dd as DropDown

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(config.INPUT_SHEET_NAME)
    Set data_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(config.DATA_SHEET_NAME)
    data_arr = data_ws.Range(data_ws.Cells(1,config.DATA_COL_DROPDOWN_INDEX),
                      data_ws.Cells(total_rows,config.DATA_COL_DROPDOWN_INDEX)).Value

    Set pack_dd = ws.Shapes(config.MAIN_DATA_DROPDOWN_NAME).OLEFormat.Object
    pack_dd.List = pack_dd
    ''' To set the index
    pack_dd.ListIndex = 1
End Sub
```

** Note -- The GetQuery function has some kinks that I haven't had time to work out, namely I don't think the HasFields option to include headers actually works.

Also I'm using DropDowns, so I'm not sure if you are using the same type of object.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi @RyanG and thank you for your answer! Can you please add an example how you connection string look like? thanks